# Cannot figure out a way to create XML schema that matches random order items with conditions

Tags: xsd

We're trying to find a way to have a schema that would validate certain rules, but we've tried various combinations of xs:all, xs:choice, xs:group and xs:sequence with no success. The rules are basically this:

1. only one occurance of the LICAPPIN01 element should occur
2. only one occurance of the LICAPPIN99 element should occur
3. there should be the same number of LICAPPIN30 and LICAPPIN31
4. there should be the same number of LICAPPIN40 and LICAPPIN41
5. there needs to be at least one set of LICAPPIN30/31 or LICAPPIN40/41 (both can be there as well)
6. For all of the above, the order does not matter -- any order is acceptable

The simplest schema we tried is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="LICAPPIN01" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="LICAPPIN30" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="LICAPPIN31" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="LICAPPIN40" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="LICAPPIN41" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="LICAPPIN99" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This has a number of problems:

- it allows multiple LICAPPIN01 and LICAPPIN99 (replacing with xs:all might fix this?)
- it does not enforce rule 3 and 4
- for rule 5, it seems to force both LICAPPIN30/31 and LICAPPIN40/41 when it should be possible to only have one of the two sets

We also tried a more complex approach with xs:group for LICAPPIN30/31 and for LICAPPIN40/41 but it broke rule 6.

Any idea if this is even possible to meet all of our basic rules? In a relatively simple Schema. In the example above, I removed all of the details within each LICAPPINnn elements -- they each contain complex types, and we don't want to have to duplicate these in multiple places, ideally.

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: Actually it's not a simple schema. The rules you have around relating nodes and the lack of them (ie any order) but without any of that being implied by a structure. Only way I know to get what you want would be something called schematron. You can do a lot more with it than what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to write a content model to meet all your requirements, but it's easy to meet all but the last.

If variation in the order of elements is essential to convey necessary information, then your best bet is to use assertions in XSD 1.1 or Schematron.  If variation in the order of elements conveys no information, then you have the option of declaring that variation in order is not a requirement after all.  The vocabulary design authorities I respect most highly say pretty consistently that if the sequence of children does not convey information, then there is no reason not to fix it.

Here is a content model that meets all the requirements you list except the last one:

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="LICAPPIN01"/>
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="LICAPPIN30"/>
        <xs:element name="LICAPPIN31"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="LICAPPIN40"/>
        <xs:element name="LICAPPIN41"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>        
    <xs:element name="LICAPPIN99"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: We'll use something like the above, and will let people know that if it is easier for them to organize the items differently, we will accept their files that way too, but that the schema can't be used unless they follow some basic ordering. Thanks.